# File upload dialog

Tags: nautilus, firefox, internet, filemanager, nemo

Is it possible to use default file manager when uploading files on Firefox (and any other browser)?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Usually you can copy path from file-manager (`Ctrl+L`, `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C` in Caja, Nautilus) and paste it to your dialog (`Ctrl+L`, `Ctrl+V`). On screenshot you have GtkFileChooserDialog, it is standard dialog for saving and opening files.

Comment: most programs also support drag&drop from the default file-manager...